# How to retrieve elements from an array without slicing?

Tags: python, arrays, element, numpy-slicing

Say I have an array, A1. B1 is another array storing the last two rows of A1. I need to retrieve the first two rows of A1 without slicing as another array (C1). Logically, I'm thinking something like A1 (the whole array) - B1 (the last two rows) = C1 (the first two rows), but I don't know if Python does anything like that. How do I get elements from an array without slicing? Appreciate your help!

`A1 = np.array([ [1, 4, 6, 8],[2, 5, 7, 10],[3, 6, 9, 13],[11, 12, 16, 0]])`
 `B1 = A1[2:4,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'subtracting' the two arrays you could delete the last two rows:

```
C1 = np.delete(A1, (2,3), axis=0)
```

```
array([[ 1,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 2,  5,  7, 10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_2_rows_of_A1():
    for i,row in enumerate(A1):
        yield row
        if i >= 1:
           break

first_2_rows = list(first_2_rows_of_A1())
```

I guess that does what you want... but I don't understand why you wouldn't just get the first two rows as `A1[:2]`

Comment: I'm not sure if A1[:2] is considered as slicing... It is my thinking that anything with colon within square brackets is considered slicing.